# Restarting a java program with a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, joptionpane, restart

I have a small problem. I just made a Tic Tac Toe game with Java with using JFrame, and Jbuttons. It works completely fine but now I ask the player if he wants to restart. Now my problem is I don't know how to restart a program. I came to where I draw new buttons on the frame, but now the `ActionListener` doesn't work anymore.
Here is the part of the code where I try to restart it

```
// here I'm asking with a JOptionPane if he wants to play again
if (input==0) {
    for(int y = 0; y<3;y++) {
        for(int x= 0; x<3;x++) {
            GUI.buttonsall[x][y].setVisible(false);
            GUI.frame.remove(GUI.buttonsall[x][y]); // these are my buttons to play tic tac toe on 
            GUI.buttonsall[x][y].removeActionListener(GUI.listener);
            GUI.buttonsall[x][y].setName(null);
        }}
    MAIN.main(null);
}
```

Comment: Comment out `GUI.buttonsall[x][y].removeActionListener(GUI.listener);`

Comment: just reset the grid , make it empty , and then players can play again

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash that doesnt work, when I reset the stuff than my actionlistiner doesnt work

Comment: @TheGoldy what exactly do u mean by that

Comment: when players play they put zero and cross in the Grid of tic tak toe , if you remove them all , then the game is reset

Comment: @TheGoldy  cleaning of the Buttons worked but then like before the Actionlisteners dont work

Comment: My guess: The ActionListener is eventually initialized outside the main-function (normally in the constructor of the class). You remove the Actionlistener, go back to main but don't recreate the Actionlistener.
But it would be easier, if you could show us the main-funtion ...

Comment: The typical way to approach this is to have a `GameModel` and a method to update the look of the GUI according to the state of the model. **General tip:** For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).